# Middleman set dynamic asset path

Tags: html, path, directory, assets, middleman

I am busy building a static site using [middleman](https://middlemanapp.com/), I have finally got it to serve correctly, only when i run `build` all my images will not show up. After a little while i think i know whats going on.

My config looks like this:

```
activate :livereload
set :relative_links, true
set :partials_dir, 'partials'
set :css_dir, 'stylesheets'
set :js_dir, 'javascripts'
set :images_dir, 'images'
set :build_dir, 'public_html'

# Build-specific configuration
configure :build do
  # For example, change the Compass output style for deployment
  activate :minify_css

  # Minify Javascript on build
  activate :minify_javascript

  # Enable cache buster
  # activate :asset_hash

  # Use relative URLs
  activate :relative_assets

  # Or use a different image path
  # set :http_prefix, "/images/"
end
```

Within my partials that i reference my images like this (note: i am using haml):

```
%ul.features
  %li.third
    %p
      %img{:src=>"../images/icon1.png", :class=>"left"}
      %span 2 days, 20 speakers, single track
```

I also have global partials that are used within every file pretty much that are now one level deeper than the partials folder.

When i run `middleman build` it compiles all my partials to html / css / js found within the `public_html` folder at the root level, but all my images are missing, upon inspecting the page i see that the images are pointing to a folder one level higher than they should be.

```
<div class='wrapper'>
  <a name='about'></a>
  <h1>
    <a alt='RubyFuza Home' href='/'>
      <img src='../images/logo.png'>
```

Below is what the directory looks like:

You will see that the source partials need to traverse up one level to get to the image folder hence the `../` before the path reference, however the files that are built using `middleman build` only need to look in the same directory level.

Is there a way to configure middleman to look for images within source at x level, but then when you have built to find the images at y level? and then just reference the images in the html like `%img{:src=>"icon1.png"}` rather than provide the whole path?

[image: directory structure.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `image tag` helper:

`<%= image_tag 'logo.svg', :alt => 'My app', :class => "logo" %>`

then the image file goes under `source/images` and in the `config.rb` you put `set :images_dir, 'images'`

Comment: Thanks thats it! i see that you can use these nifty rails helpers